# Velocity template string concatenation

Tags: velocity, velocity-template-language

It is my first time to use [VTL](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html#velocity-template-language-vtl-an-introduction), and I tried to follow the documentation about string concatenation, but I can’t make it work. Here is the scenario:

I have a payload:

```
{
     "name":{
          "firstname": "John",
          "lastname": "Doe"
     }
}
```

The result I got was:

```
{
     "fullname": "John"-"Doe"
}
```

Also, how can I get the current date ([UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)) in Velocity?

In my Velocity template, I did:

```
#set($firstname=  $root.name.firstname)
#set($lastname=  $root.name.lastname)
#set($fullname=  ${firstname}-${lastname})
{
     $h.outputFormat("json")
     $h.opt("fullname", $fullname, true)
}
```

The result I want is:

```
{
     "fullname": "John-Doe"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the `$h` object in your velocity context represents, but the JSON output you are expecting can be achieved without it, with a template like the below:

```
#set($firstname= $root.name.firstname)
#set($lastname=$root.name.lastname)
#set($fullname="${firstname}-${lastname}")
{
     "fullname": "$fullname"
}
```

**Date:**

To access the date within the template, you'd need to have a [DateTool](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/3.0/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/DateTool.html) object in your velocity context. To add it to the context, do something like the below:

```java
velocityContext.put("date", new DateTool())
```

Once the DateTool object is present in the context, just `$date` would give you the date/time in the current time zone, in a format like `Feb 10, 2024, 7:46:11 PM` and `$date.getDate().toInstant()` would give you the date/time in UTC, in the format `2024-02-11T01:46:11.721Z`